# how to call a function in a procedure?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-ebs, oracle-apps

I have a concern where in I need to call the package body function using a procedure which must return value which I can use in xml publisher report where clause which will call the function value in report query and i have tried writing the procedure in the same body underneath the function but the difficulty is i'm unable to call the function and return the value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY XXMTZ_WO_STG_REP_TRI_TEST
AS
   FUNCTION before_report
      RETURN BOOLEAN
   IS
   --
   BEGIN
      --
      fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG, 'Entering the IF Block');

      --
      IF     data_source = p_datasource
         AND p_module = 'AP'
         AND p_processing_status = 'Processed'
      THEN
         --
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P' AND d_ap_flag = 'P';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'AP'
            AND p_processing_status = 'Un Processed'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P' AND d_ap_flag = 'Y';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'AP'
            AND p_processing_status = 'ERROR'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P' AND d_ap_flag = 'E';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'AP'
            AND p_processing_status = 'DELETED'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'R';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'AR'
            AND p_processing_status = 'Processed'
      THEN
         --
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P' AND d_ar_flag = 'P';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'AR'
            AND p_processing_status = 'Un Processed'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P' AND d_ar_flag = 'Y';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'AR'
            AND p_processing_status = 'ERROR'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P' AND d_ar_flag = 'E';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'AR'
            AND p_processing_status = 'DELETED'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'R';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'MTE'
            AND p_processing_status = 'Processed'
      THEN
         --
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P' AND d_mte_flag = 'P';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'MTE'
            AND p_processing_status = 'Un Processed'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P' AND d_mte_flag = 'Y';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'MTE'
            AND p_processing_status = 'ERROR'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P' AND d_mte_flag = 'E';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'MTE'
            AND p_processing_status = 'DELETED'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'R';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'Pre Interface'
            AND p_processing_status = 'Processed'
      THEN
         --
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'P';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'Pre Interface'
            AND p_processing_status = 'Un Processed'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'N';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'Pre Interface'
            AND p_processing_status = 'ERROR'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'E';
      ELSIF     data_source = p_datasource
            AND p_module = 'Pre Interface'
            AND p_processing_status = 'DELETED'
      THEN
         LP_REP_WHERE := d_process_flag = 'R';
      END IF;

      --
      fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG, 'EXIT of IF Block');
      RETURN TRUE;
   --
   END before_report;

END XXMTZ_WO_STG_REP_TRI_TEST;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Be sure that your `before_report` function is defined in the spec portion of the package.
2. The `BOOLEAN` type is not available in SQL. If you want to call this function from an SQL statement you'll need to return something like 'Y' or 'N' as a VARCHAR2 value.

### Edit

If you want to define a procedure to call your function you'd do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XXMTZ_WO_STG_REP_TRI_TEST AS  -- package spec
  PROCEDURE PROC_TO_CALL_FUNCTION;
  FUNCTION BEFORE_REPORT RETURN BOOLEAN;
END XXMTZ_WO_STG_REP_TRI_TEST;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY XXMTZ_WO_STG_REP_TRI_TEST AS  -- package body
  PROCEDURE PROC_TO_CALL_FUNCTION
  IS
    bValue  BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    bValue := XXMTZ_WO_STG_REP_TRI_TEST.BEFORE_REPORT;
  END PROC_TO_CALL_FUNCTION;

  FUNCTION BEFORE_REPORT
      RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
  BEGIN
    -- function body goes here

    RETURN TRUE;
  END BEFORE_REPORT;
END XXMTZ_WO_STG_REP_TRI_TEST;
/
```

Comment: hey! Before report function is declared in spec of the package. I want to call the function through a procedure something like this procedure call(ref out varchar2(400)) before_report(ref); end;

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking. Do you mean that you want to define a procedure in the package spec named `call`, which will then invoke your `before_report` function?

Comment: OK, I added an example of how to define the package body, the procedure, and the function. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks! @Bob Jarvis. Can I also use the same code with function return type as varchar2?

Comment: Yes. Best of luck.